# How to change a line immediately following a match pattern

Tags: sed, inline-editing

I need a sed one liner to change a line immediately following the pattern [lb]:

```
[lb]
enabled=0
```

to change to:

```
[lb]
enabled=1
```

Thanks to all you experts in advance for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

IMO, sed is not really the right tool, but you can do:

```
sed '/^\[lb\]/{ N; s/enabled=0/enabled=1/; }' input
```

Comment: This is precisely what I am looking for and works perfect. Jut out of curiosity, what do you think is the better solution? and Thanks a TON BTW

Comment: I was thinking an awk solution would be cleaner, or perl, but after more consideration I think sed does just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not your homework.

```
sed  '/\[1b\]/,+1s/enabled=0/enabled=1/' <input-file>
```

Comment: The `+1` address is non-portable.  I believe it is valid in gnu-sed

Comment: heh, not homework just not as expert in sed/awk as I would like to be. Thanks!

Comment: stackflow ate my '\'. Precede the bracket characters with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -i -r '/\[lb\]/ { N; s/(enabled=)0/\11/; }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\\[.*\\]"; ORS=OFS="" } { gsub("enabled=0", "enabled=1"); print RT, $0 }'
```